# Looking for background material about the Midgard Derwisch

Tags: background

We are about to start a game of [Midgard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midgard_(role-playing_game)) 3rd edition were we will be playing the *Sturm über Mokattam* adventure. I want to play the Derwisch class but I found little on how to roleplay it.

Is there any book or online resource where I can find more about how to it is meant to be played apart from the rules aspect of "they follow this good and fight with two sabers of that kind, using magical dances to work magic"

The adventure has some background infos about the region of Eschar and the caliphate of Mokattam were it takes place and about its inhabitants and culture but of that I know only what the gm provided because, being in the adventure I didn't read it myself. And there seems to be little about the Derwisch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blurb from the [Midgard Wiki](http://www.midgard-wiki.de) about the Derwisch (aka Dervish). That article does not contain much but you can get more by delving deeper into the articles.

### Derwisch

> The Dervish is a strictly believing Dhulam. Alone or in small faith groups he studied in the Desert Storm eschar for perfection. For the most part, the dervishes belong to the order of the dancing dervishes . The caliph of Mokattam used dervishes as a battalion; They fight two- handedly with the Nimcha sword. A typical type of their sorcery are the magic dances . [(Link)](http://www.midgard-wiki.de/index.php/Derwisch)

Derwisch are a group of holy warriors somewhat resembling Muslim warriors during the middle ages. Faith is a huge part of their lives and most of their decisions revolve around the impact their decisions might have on their souls in the afterlife.

### Din Dhulahi

Derwisch are strictly believing Dhulam which are believers of Din Dhulahi (aka The Duality). They believe in the duality of their gods [Ormut](http://www.fantasy-und-rollenspiel.de/mythologie/midgard.php) (Light) and [Alaman](http://www.fantasy-und-rollenspiel.de/mythologie/midgard.php) (Darkness).

> In order that they may not depart from the right path, Ormut has given each of them two guardian angels, one protects the body, the other the soul. Alaman, on the other hand, has given them a spirit to lead them into temptation and thus to Alaman. After the death of a believer, the result of this lifelong struggle between the guardians and the spirit decides about the life after death. Either the soul lives to the end of the world in the light heaven of Ormut, or it must serve the Iblisi Alamans (Creatures that come from Alaman's Blood that brought sickness and death to creation). ([Link](http://www.midgard-wiki.de/index.php/Zweiheitsglaube))

### [Bids and prohibitions of the Dhulahim](http://www.midgard-wiki.de/index.php/Zweiheitsglaube)

- Dhulahim must pay tribute to Ormut at sunrise and sunset and at noon.
- Dhulahim must never extinguish a fire except in emergencies.
- Dhulahim are not
  allowed to use fire for low purposes (for example, to burn trash).
- Dhulahim must honor the dead and not rob them (unbelievers are
  excluded in many places).
- Dhulahim must light a memorial fire in the
  night of the Aid el-Uled ed-Dhar and honor the dead.
- Dhulahim must
  observe the fasting time before the new moon of the light bird.
- Dhulahim shall not shed blood in the noon, except sacrifices and war.
- Dhulahim must never stand so that their own shadow falls upon the
  heart of another Dhulam.
- Dhulahim must not smoke.

*The original translation of the second prohibition was "Dhulahim must never extinguish a fire except a fire." but it used different words for either fire, the first just being Feuer (fire) but the second one Brand could be read as Blaze so I think the intent here is to say "Don't put out fires unless it's out of control"*